# Why for git pull merging is the default behavior?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull

Usually when we update our local repository with new origin commits we do git fetch, git rebase. But we don't do git fetch git merge. Usually, the reason is that we don't want to add a new commit (merge commit) but just want to get all new commits on top of our code. So why then the default behavior for git pull is not with merge. I know that we can change it, but is there is better reason to use fetch-merge over fetch-rebase.

Comment: Because it's a shorthand for `git fetch & git merge FETCH_HEAD`. Or did I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 13):

I assume your question is why with `git pull` the default behavior is to merge instead of to rebase the pulled-in changes.

The answer is rather simple: Rebasing recreates the commits that are being rebased. Those new commit objects then replace the old ones. But those new commits are completely incompatible with the old ones. This causes all other users who have pulled the original commits before to have incompatible commits from the rebased ones you just recreated. So you have two conflicting versions with mostly the same change. This usually means a lot of problems since you need to fix these conflicts manually (by saying which of the two versions to keep; so if you rebased, the other ones all need to throw the old ones away—manually).

This is also why you should *never rebase commits that have been published*.

So the default solution is to *merge*, as merging is a completely safe operation that will not cause conflicts. Merge commits are just commits that are *added* to the history, but do not replace the existing history. Yes, it may make the history a bit more complex, but it’s completely transparent and compatible with all versions that existed before.

Of course, there are some situations in which rebasing is just fine. Most notably if you work locally on some unpublished changes and you want to update your repository. Then fetching and rebasing *your local changes* is fine since they only belong to yourself and nobody else knows about them yet. But this should always be an explicit action, so you don’t make any mistakes. And that’s why the rebasing pull is just an option: `git pull -r`.

Comment: Poke, what I ask is when you update your local code with commits in the origin. So in this case you, I guess, suggest to rebase. And this is what I say, for updating the local code you should use `pull`, right? And `pull` in not doing `rebase`. You don' use `pull` in other cases then to update the local code, correct?

Comment: You can use `git pull -r` to rebase your local changes instead of merging them (this is essentially the same as fetch followed by rebase; but shorter). But yeah, you should only do this for *local* changes that nobody else has received. In all other situations (and when in doubt), just merge using just `git pull`.

Comment: Poke, in order to merge I fetch-rebase both branches and I do get merge. This is not optimal? Should I use `pull` for merging to branches on my local repo?

Comment: If the commits you rebase only exist locally, and you never published them, then you can rebase. Otherwise, just merge. (`pull` is the same as fetch & merge; `pull -r` is the same as fetch & rebase)

Comment: Is this answer out-of-date? Does this answer take into account `fast-forward` rebasing?  I routinely fetch commits from a remote and then rebase to the `origin/main` branch commit, without any trouble. This does not change the hash IDs of the commits I received from `origin`.

Comment: @JonathanBenn There is no rebase happening when you can just fast-forward just like there is no merge happening when pulling with a merge resolution strategy when pull can just fast-forward. – The answer (and question) assumes the situation where you have diverging local and remote branches.

Comment: @poke Good point! Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3):

I think it works this way by default to avoid rewriting local history, and changing hashes of existing commits. These commits might be already pushed to the remote. The `rebase` is a destructive command, and pulling changes from the remote shouldn't destruct anything by default.

You can use `git pull --rebase` or just create an alias for this action.

Comment: But if you add new merge commit, you affect the history. Because in origin that merge commit is not present.

Comment: @Narek I meant existing commits shouldn't be changed.

Comment: @Narek, there's a big difference between *adding a new commit at the tip of a branch* (a new merge commit) and *rewriting existing commits to have new hashes* (rebasing).

Comment: @Chris while you `rebase` from `origin` on the local branch after the fetch, the commits' SHA-1 stays the same, right?

Comment: @Narek, no. Git commit hashes are based on several things, one of which is the hash(es) of it's parent commit(s). When you rebase you change the commit's parents, so the hash changes. This is transitive; every descendent commit's hash changes as well by the same mechanism.

Comment: @Chris but it stays. I have always done this and it has always added the changes from origin with exactly the same SHA-1.

Comment: @Narek it changes hashes of your local (not pushed yet) commits, as they become based on new codebase (that you just pulled).

If you use git in central repository scenario (like replacement for CVS/SVN), you usually need to do `git pull --rebase`, as merge commits are useless in such case.

Comment: @Stas yes I do use it as a central repo. We never push or pull on teammates local repos. Only on origin (github/bitbucket). Hence, I guess I don't need pull with merge behavior.

Comment: @Narek exactly. I do the same for our corporative git repo. We use merge only for project merges. Rebase is used much more often to prepare local commits for push.

Comment: @Narek, I misunderstood earlier. The commits you rebase _onto_ do retain their hashes. But your assertion that it is safe for the local commits' hashes to change _depends on your chosen workflow_. There is nothing inherently safe about rebasing. On the contrary, it is inherently risky. Your workflow, where local commits are never shared, gives you some measure of insurance. But this is not guaranteed by Git. Remember, it is a very flexible tool. How can Git know that you've never shared those commits? Should it have to? The safer option, and therefore the better default, is to merge.